# draw 2 pairs of resizable rectangles in matlab

Tags: matlab, rectangles

I have a program that should draw 2 re sizable rectangle in matlab. drawing two resizable is ok, but I want to change size in the same time, I mean when I change size of the first one, the second'size change too. but I don know haw to connect them together. can any body help me?!
thanks.
here is my code:

```
figure,imshow('image.jpg');
h1 = imrect(gca, [10 10 300 500]);
h2 = imrect(gca, [200 200 400 300]);
```

Comment: Please put your current code with two individually resizeable rectangles into your question. Probably an answer is only a minor modification to this code.

Comment: the code added, thanks Daniel.

Comment: whit mouse click and move... what do you mean thewaywewalk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this you have to use the `addNewPositionCallback`.

Write your own function implementing the logic you need. This example sets all rectangles to the same size:

```
function myPositionFunction(allRects,changed,position)
    %iterate over all rectangles
    for idx=1:numel(allRects)
        %skip the currently changed one
        if idx~=changed
            %get position, modify it and set it
            thisP=allRects(idx).getPosition();
            thisP(3:4)=position(3:4);
            allRects(idx).setPosition(thisP);
        end
    end
end
```

Now the tricky part, how make practical usable callback:

```
figure
imshow('board.tif')
h1 = imrect(gca, [10 10 20 20]);
h2 = imrect(gca, [20 20 30 30]);
addNewPositionCallback(h1,@(p)myPositionFunction([h1,h2],1,p))
addNewPositionCallback(h2,@(p)myPositionFunction([h1,h2],2,p))
```

This way your callback is called with:

```
-first parameter a list of all rectangles (could be extended to more than two)
-second parameter the index of the changed rectangle
-third parameter the new boundaries of the changed rectangle
```

Comment: is it possible to have coordinates real-time ?! by BluePos = wait(h1); I have them, after mouse double click. but if I change position and resize the rect again, BluePos doesn't change :(

Comment: @Negar always call getPosition when you use it. Then it's up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I see @Daniel has just posted an answer, but here is an alternative solution using addNewPositionCallback as well.

1) First create a function in which you draw a first rectangle, and add the callback:

```
function Draw2Rect(~)
global h1 

A = imread('peppers.png');

imshow(A);

h1 = imrect(gca,[20 20 200 150]);

addNewPositionCallback(h1,@UpdateRect)
```

2) Then define the anonymous function called by the callback, in which you 1st use findobj in order to find rectangles drawn in the current axes. imrect objects are of the type 'hggroup'. Basically you look for all the rectangles present and as you move the first rectangle previous ones are deleted and a new rectangle is drawn. Here I used a dummy relation between the positions but you get the idea.

```
function UpdateRect(~)

global h1 % Simpler to use global variables but there are more robust alternatives!

Rect1Pos = getPosition(h1); % Get the position of your rectangle of interest

hRect = findobj(gca,'Type','hggroup'); % Find all rectangle objects

if numel(hRect>1) Once you start changing the first rectangle position, delete others.
delete(hRect(1:end-1))
h2 = imrect(gca,round(Rect1Pos/2));
end
```

I don't know how to post animated gifs in answers, but here are 2 images showing the 1st rectangle and then the 2 rectangles after moving the first one:

1:

[image]

2:

[image]

Hope that helps! As noted I used h1 as a global variable to easily pass data between functions, but there are more robust alternatives you can use.

Comment: thank you so much Benoit, but Daniel's ​​answer, that is what I want.